# Root user can't remove folder

Tags: linux-mint, rm, fsck

There is a folder /mnt/shared which root user can't access/modify or remove.

```
# ls -lai /mnt
total 4
16662 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Mar 27 14:30 .
    2 drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Mar 27 14:26 ..
16663 dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Mar 27 14:30 shared

# chattr -i /mnt/shared/
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /mnt/shared/

# rmdir /mnt/shared/
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/mnt/shared/’: Permission denied

# cd /mnt/shared/
-su: cd: /mnt/shared/: No such file or directory

# ls -i /mnt
16663 shared
# find . -inum 16663 -delete
find: `./shared': No such file or directory
```

Running fsck doesn't help.
OS: Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: please add output of mount, also have you tried rebooting the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found what caused an issue - autofs.
After stopping autofs service undeleteable folder disappeared.

```
#service autofs stop
```

Comment: You should "accept" this answer (even though you're the one who wrote it) by clicking on the checkmark to the left.  This will let people know that the problem has been solved.  Since you are a new user, you might need to wait a few hours before you can do that.

Comment: thanks btw! I wonder why it acts like that instead of a normal mount point, its really pretty annoying. I'd *like* to replace the downed NFS server with a normal volume but noooooooooooo.......

Answer (score -1):

Try to it with Knoppix Live! Just boot Knoppix as live system on your Linux-Mint computer then you should be able to edit/ delete this folder!

If this doesn't work then it is possible that this path is defect!

Comment: I tried to access this folder from Mint LiveCD, but it doesn't show such folder on the disk.